# shifting indices to the left in a struct unsorted array

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I have this snippet of my overall program. In this function and particular this piece of the program the user inputs an MLS# for a home to be deleted from the array. The first "for" statement searches for the MLS# and then null's all data. I am having issues in the next 
"for" statement. Moving all data to the left after the indices have been nulled. The data stored in the struct array is as follows:

```
struct mlsListing { int mlsNum;           // Struct Array holds one line of the struct
                    double price;         // mlsListing 
                    int type; 
                    string zip; 
                    string company; 
                    string realty; 
                  }; 
 const int MAX_LISTINGS = 750;  
        mlsListing houseData[MAX_LISTINGS]; 
 const int NOT_FOUND = -1;
 int targetMLS; // Variable for target MLS
 int mlsDelete; // Variable for target MLS found
 int mlsCounter;// Counter for finding target MLS 
 int count;     // Array Counter


// Function 

void {

 cout << "Enter the MLS# you wish to delete: "; 
           cin >> targetMLS;                       // User input MLS#


        for (mlsCounter = 0; ((mlsCounter < count) && (mlsDelete == NOT_FOUND));
                                 mlsCounter++) {

                 if (houseData[mlsCounter].mlsNum == targetMLS) {

                    mlsDelete = houseData[mlsCounter].mlsNum; 

                    houseData[mlsCounter].mlsNum = 0; 
                    houseData[mlsCounter].price = 0;
                    houseData[mlsCounter].type = 0;
                    houseData[mlsCounter].zip.clear(); 
                    houseData[mlsCounter].company.clear();
                    houseData[mlsCounter].realty.clear(); 
                  }
          }


         // Shifting indices to the left after deletion?

          for (move = mlsCounter;move < count; move++){

              houseData[move].mlsNum = houseData[move+1].mlsNum; 
              houseData[move].price = houseData[move+1].price; 
              houseData[move].type = houseData[move+1].type; 
              houseData[move].zip = houseData[move+1].zip; 
              houseData[move].company = houseData[move+1].company;
              houseData[move].realty = houseData[move+1].realty;  
          } 

         count--; 
}
```

Comment: One word: [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Another word: [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).

Comment: Agreed, but I'm trying to do it by using a struct.

Comment: Well you can still use e.g. `find_if` on old C-style arrays. Also, since you are copying over the "deleted" entry, you don't need to "null all data". You also don't have top copy all fields one by one, the compiler is perfectly able to generate that code for you if you do e.g. `houseData[move] = houseData[move + 1];`.

Comment: Joachim, Thanks for your input. Your example will be much better for reading and less typing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What that's doing is removing that item from its position in the array, by going through all remaining items and moving them one closer (and then decrementing the count in the end.)

Simplified example:

Say you had a simpler array that just contained characters.  Let's have an array of 10 characters:

```
Array position :   [0]  [1]  [2]  [3]  [4]  [5]  [6]  [7]  [8]  [9]
Values in array:    a    l    p    h    a    b    e    t    i    c
```

How would you remove the letter in position [5] (i.e., the 'b')?  You'd move all the remaining letters over, so it would look like this:

```
Array position :   [0]  [1]  [2]  [3]  [4]  [5]  [6]  [7]  [8]  [9]
Values in array:    a    l    p    h    a    e    t    i    c
```

This is exactly what the for loop you see is doing.  It's doing it to every part of the structure, effectively copying all the parts of the structure in the next index into the previous one.

If I recall correctly, that's unnecessary with structs.  I believe you should just be able to say `houseData[move] = houseData[move+1]`, and it will simply bitwise copy the latter into the former.

#### Edit

Based on comment/discussion, the issue is different.  You just need to break out of your upper for loop at the right time.  You also need to set your second loop to not go out of bounds.

```
for (mlsCounter = 0; ((mlsCounter < count) && (mlsDelete == NOT_FOUND));
                             mlsCounter++) {

             if (houseData[mlsCounter].mlsNum == targetMLS) {

                mlsDelete = houseData[mlsCounter].mlsNum; 

                houseData[mlsCounter].mlsNum = 0; 
                houseData[mlsCounter].price = 0;
                houseData[mlsCounter].type = 0;
                houseData[mlsCounter].zip.clear(); 
                houseData[mlsCounter].company.clear();
                houseData[mlsCounter].realty.clear(); 

                break;
              }
      }

   for (move = mlsCounter;move < count - 1; move++){
```

Comment: Scott, In my opinion my code should be working, but there is still something not right, can't put my finger on it. The data doesn't seem to shift.

Comment: Ok, I thought you just didn't understand what that loop was doing.  Are you certain the first loop is going ok?  In the snippet you provide, you don't ever set mlsDelete to NOT_FOUND.  (And before the second loop, you should exit out if mlsDelete == NOT_FOUND.)  And Keval brings up a good point - you are going out of bounds, though that wouldn't prevent you from seeing a shift.

Comment: @llSpectrell Run it in a debugger, and step through the code line by line.

Comment: One final issue, which might be what you're seeing:  Your top loop sets mlsCounter one higher than it should.  Using my character example above, when mlsCounter = 5, you'd set mlsDelete.  Then you'd set mlsCounter to 6, then see that mlsDelete is no longer NOT_FOUND.  Below, you'll be starting by moving position 7 to position 6, and so on, but you'll never move anything into position 5.  The result would be the word alpha\0tic (treating the \0 as my easier version of clearing the data.)

Comment: Im running DevC++ compiler. It appears that its nulling the index I select and the last index on the array, nothing is shifting.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Scott. I didn't realize that my counter was not at the correct index for the next "for" statement. It had me stumped for quite a while. I appreciate your assistance. I saw your profile. Im from Houston as well.

Answer (score 2):

The second for loop is going out of bounds. It must be:

```
for (move = mlsCounter;move < count - 1; move++)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a list would be a betterly suited data structure for that task. Plus, in any case, you should consider using a container provided by the standard library if possible.

```
std::list<mlsListing> housedata; // so you can easily add stuff at the end, and remove stuff in the middle at low cost

std::remove_if( housedata.begin(), housedata.end(), 
                [&](mlsListing current) -> bool 
                {
                    if (current.mlsNum == targetMLS)
                    {
                        mlsDelete = current.mlsNum;
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
              )
```